# APPLET tag missing CODE parameter - not really?

Tags: java, parameters, applet

I am trying to implement this demo on my local machine. http://bit.ly/4g4o1r

I have placed these 3 files in a folder:

```
LittleShootApplet.class
appletLoader.js
filepath.html
```

I have pointed my browser to that location but I keep getting applet missing code parameter even though it does?!

```
APPLET tag missing CODE parameter.
java.lang.NullPointerException: name
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel$7.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.AppletViewer.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the JS that generates the applet HTML: http://bit.ly/4yYuwa

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks all

Comment: Can you write the full answer and accept it as correct (so it doesn't keep showing as unresolved?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a small mistake in file path! Sorry for wasting time.